# To make grid in List View appeared in IDE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I am using VS2010 Windows Form

Here's the list view after I dropped it to the windows form, and after adding the column, using columns attribute in the IDE.

[image]

I wish that I can have something like below display in the IDE, what attributes should I change?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following (assuming you are adding the columns at design time):

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

[image]